# Loading a Dynamic Array into a SQL query with IN operator

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an Array `$f_array` whose values are loaded by `while` loops and SQL Query.

I want to use this array name in a SQL Query.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM comment WHERE uname IN ($f_array) ORDER BY ID DESC";
```

This is what my array looks like after the data is loaded,

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "wisahmed" 
    [1]=> string(10) "test_user1" 
    [2]=> string(10) "test_user2" 
    [3]=> string(10) "test_user3" 
}
```

Could someone tell me how can I load this array into the above MySQL Query.

Comment: PS: Im only a beginner. I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: Show your second SQL query

Comment: So the source of `$f_array` is itself a query? If so, you're probably better of using a `join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a quoted, comma separated list. This is easily accomplished from an array source with implode:

```
$imploded = implode("','", $f_array)
```

This would render:

```
wisahmed','test_user1','test_user2','test_user3
```

So wrapping that in single quotes and putting it in your existing query results in proper formatting:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM comment WHERE uname IN ('{$imploded}') ORDER BY ID DESC";
```

Becoming:

```
SELECT * FROM comment WHERE uname IN ('wisahmed','test_user1','test_user2','test_user3') ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

### First convert array to string

```
$array = ["wisahmed", "test_user1", "test_user2", "test_user3"];
$users = implode(",", $array);
```

**Update your query**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM comment WHERE uname IN($users) ORDER BY ID DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the array directly, you have to transform it to string first so try the following:

```
$users = "'".implode("','",$f_array)."'";
```

and then the query should be

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM comment WHERE uname IN ($users) ORDER BY ID DESC";
```